# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object when I run new_topic(), though there is a return

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

```
def new_topic(request):
    """add new topic"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:           
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

The error I got:

**The view learning_logs.views.new_topic didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

And I have searched many related problems as well as tested them, yet they did not work.Could you please give me some help,thanks.

Comment: Almost certainly the indentation is not as you have shown it here. Please update your post with what you actually have.

Comment: After I saw your comment, I have checked my original document again and am sure  the indentation is the same as it is here. And thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_topic(request):
    """add new topic"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
    else:
        form = TopicForm()
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks, and I tested it, yet still the same result.

Comment: Please add urls

Comment: yes I added it in the urls.py as follows:
 url(r'^new_topic$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic')

Comment: Can you please add html, form and full view.

Comment: I got it today, and I exchanged a port(from 8080 to 8000), which runned successfully.Thanks, friend.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the server when it is running.